# Invertir cadenas en C++ no compila

Tags: c++, array

hace casi un mes publiqué una pregunta en la que no podía invertir cadenas en C++, probé cada código que me habían brindado y ninguno me funcionó. Busqué la solución en Youtube y encontré este código, sin embargo, al ejecutarse el programa, no muestra nada. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    /* Invertir una cadena*/
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include<string.h>
     #define tamano 30

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    
    char cadena[tamano]= "Silvana";
    char cadena2[tamano];
     int n,i,j;

     n=strlen(cadena);

    j=0;

    for(i=n-1;n>=0;i--){
    
    cadena2[j]=cadena[i];
    
    j++;
    
    cadena2[j]='\0';
   
    }

    cout<<cadena2<<endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cadena2[j]='\0';` debe ir fuera del bucle for. Probalo y si sigue tu problema nos dices.

Comment: La condición del ciclo no es correcta, debería ser `i>=0` en lugar de `n>=0`.

Comment: Sugiero que en lugar de incluir capturas a la pregunta que hiciste, coloques su URL.

Answer (score 0):

Una vez tienes la palabra en un string, para invertir la palabra puedes usar std::reverse

```
std::string inversa = palabra;
std::reverse(inversa.begin(), inversa.end());
```

Ejemplo de que funciona [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PEPbs8jW0pK3SB0a)

O también puedes invertir la cadena usando el constructor correspondiente de std::string:

```
std::string inversa(palabra.rbegin(), palabra.rend());
```

Ejemplo funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RGip4qNE4neacDuE)

Si no quieres dar el paso a std::string, aún puedes seguir usando std::reverse. Esta función espera recibir dos punteros (inicio y fin) o dos iteradores, por lo que puede ser usada por un array de C.

El único problema en este caso es que hay que *restar 1* a `end` para no mover el caracter que finaliza la cadena al inicio de la misma, resultando en una cadena vacía:

```
char palabra[] = "abcdef";
std::reverse(std::begin(palabra), std::end(palabra) - 1);
```

Ejemplo funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XVX4F7DESS2az8jB)

Hasta aquí la respuesta que te di hace un mes. Vale, el ultimo caso tenía un fallo, pero como ves, todos funcionan.

Otra cosa es que a la hora de probarlos debas incluir las librerías donde se encuentran las funciones... no está de más que te acostumbres a buscar dónde se encuentran las funciones

Hablando ahora de tu código, ya te han dado la solución via comentarios:

> La condición del ciclo no es correcta, debería ser i>=0 en lugar de n>=0. –
> don_aman

Y luego como mejora, el primer comentario:

> cadena2[j]='\0'; debe ir fuera del bucle for. Probalo y si sigue tu problema nos dices. –
> Dreyf

Es decir:

```
for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--){  
    cadena2[j]=cadena[i];
    j++;
}
cadena2[j]='\0';
```